# WebView2: Click a button to show website in WebView window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webview2

I'm new to C# and Visual Studio altogether. I'm trying to create a WebView2 window that has a couple buttons (Google, YouTube, Microsoft) with a WebView beneath. When one of those buttons is clicked, I would like the WebView to show the webpage of the associated URL i.e. when I click the "Google" button, the Google page will open in the below WebView.

Can this be done? Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it.

You can refer to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.961.33).

Generally, the code is written into the click event.

Like：

```
 webView.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.com.hk/");
```

Comment: [document is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms#step-5---navigation)